# onChange prop value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, primereact

I'm using reactprime TreeSelect. I want to create an array by editing the variable named `returnArray` and send it to the main component's state via props. But `onChange` seems undefined. Same process was working in `OnValueChanged`.

**Main Component:**

```
return(
          <SubComponent>
            onChange={(val) => {
              console.log("here")
            if (val)
              setFormDataDetails({
                ...formDataDetails,
                [item.NS_CI_ID]: val,
              });
          }}
          </SubComponent>
);
```

**SubComponent:**

```
  const nodeStateCh = (e) => {
    setSelectedNodeKeys(e.value)
    let rArray= []
    rArray.push("test")
    if (props.onChange) {  //undefined...
      props.onChange(returnArray)
    }
    
  }



  return (
    <div className="card flex justify-content-center">
      <TreeSelect
        value={selectedNodeKeys}
        onChange={nodeStateCh}
        options={nodes}
        metaKeySelection={false}
        filter
        className="md:w-20rem w-full"
        selectionMode="checkbox"
        display="chip"
        placeholder="Select Items"
      >
        {' '}
      </TreeSelect>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Where is `nodeStateCh` getting called? At the moment, your code doesn't seem to use it. Unless `onChange={nodeState}` is a typo in the question and is supposed to be `onChange={nodeStateCh}`, in which case, please fix the typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you passed your onChange as a child, not as a param, this is why porpos are empty.

Instead of this:

```
 <SubComponent>
     onChange={(val) => {
         console.log("here")
         if (val)
           setFormDataDetails({
                ...formDataDetails,
                [item.NS_CI_ID]: val,
           });
     }}
 </SubComponent>
```

It should be like this:

```
 <SubComponent
     onChange={(val) => {
         console.log("here")
         if (val)
           setFormDataDetails({
                ...formDataDetails,
                [item.NS_CI_ID]: val,
           });
     }}
 />
```

And then, you pass this function as a param called onChange.

In your method, you passed this also as a param, but special param called children, but it is for different purpose.

You can read more about that in docs:
https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children